# finding location using geocoder api in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, google-geocoder, geocoder

I have a series of city name in pandas dataframe. For that I need to find out the address of particular city and store them at separate column in the same dataframe. City column contain  NaN values too. I am getting address for a given location / city name separately. But it is not working in a pandas dataframe

```
data = [['madurai',10],['NaN',12],['hosur',13]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Age'])
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim()
for i in df.Name:
    if i == "NaN":
       continue
    loc = geolocator.geocode(i)
address = loc.address
print(address)
```

It is working for the data frame but returns the last address alone and not for the  entire 3 cities. If we change the order like below,

```
data = [['Nan',10],['Madurai',12],['hosur',13]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Age'])
```

I am getting the error : GeocoderTimedOut: Service timed out

Query:
 1. I want the results (address) to be saved in a column
 2. How to process Nan values

Answer (score 0):

You can add a column with the addresses in this way:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['madurai',10],['NaN',12],['hosur',13]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Age'])
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim()
for i in df.Name:
    if i == "NaN":
        continue
    df.loc[df.Name == i, 'Address'] = geolocator.geocode(i)

print(df)
```

Comment: getting an error : ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Comment: The problem is that `geolocator.geocode(i)` returns a sequence instead of a value. What does `print(geolocator.geocode(i))` returns? I don't have your data so I cannot reproduce, but if you put a generic string in `df.loc[df.Name == i, 'Address'] = 'address_string'` the code works as expected, so try to fix that part. Maybe `geolocator.geocode(i)[0]` is enough...

Answer (score 0):

You only get the last values because you keep replacing `loc`each time in the loop.
The `GeocoderTimedOut: Service timed out` error arises because you are making to many requests to the server. You should include a `sleep` between the requests. If you still get this error take a look at this: [Link - Avoid time out](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173569/avoid-time-out-error-nominatim-geopy-open-street-maps)

Try:

```
import pandas as pd
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
import time

data = [['madurai',10],['NaN',12],['hosur',13]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Age'])
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent='test')
address = []
for i in df.Name:
    time.sleep(3)
    if i == "NaN":
       address.append('NaN')
       continue    
    address.append(geolocator.geocode(i))

df['address'] = address
```

Answer (score 0):

I introduced timedelay between requests as below and few lines to view progress bar

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim()
from geopy.extra.rate_limiter import RateLimiter
geocode = RateLimiter(geolocator.geocode, min_delay_seconds=1)
final['Geolocation'] = final['city'].apply(geocode)
from tqdm import tqdm
tqdm.pandas()
final['Geolocation'] = final['city'].progress_apply(geocode)
```

It works now.